# Is it possible to set a max amount of screens that can be running at once?

Tags: centos, gnu-screen

I'd like to know is it possible to set a max amount of screens that could be running at
once on screenrc? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to recompile screen to be able to edit this option.  You need to manipulate the "MAXWIN" flag.

> I usually recompile screen to remove it. If you want to do it with
>   packages, make sure you have the dpkg-dev package installed (you will
>   need make etc. so also grab build-essential which may or may not be a
>   dependancy on dpkg-dev) and use 'apt-get source screen' to grab the
>   source for screen.
>
> Extract the source (screen_4.0.3.orig.tar.gz). Make sure that you run
>   the patch after the archive is extracted to create the debian package
>   control files. Edit the config.h.in file and find this near the top:
>
> :# define MAXWIN 40
>
> Change the 40 to what ever limit you want.
>
> Rebuild the package using dpkg-buildpackage and then install the .dpkg
>   file over the top of your current screen installation. This will then
>   set the window limit to what ever you defined earlier.

This explains how to increase the limit, but decreasing should be the same.  Good luck!

[source](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/01/msg01003.html)

Comment: Windows may not be the same as screens. And you're giving information for debian/ubuntu when the question is flagged centos.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was under the impression that screen should run similarly across distros.  If this ends up not being the case, @dickweed can downvote to get it out of the rotation.